# CSS keyframe animations working on one selector but not others

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I have the following simple keyframe animations defined in my CSS file, and even though the first is working fine, I'm having trouble getting the second two to work:

```
.hi p {
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20rem;
  color: #f7c089;
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: hiAnimation 1.5s ease-in;
}

@keyframes hiAnimation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -2rem;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0rem;
  }
}

.intro-name {
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #bababa;
  font-weight: 400;
  animation: nameAnimation 1.5s ease-in;
}

@keyframes nameAnimation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: -2rem;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 0rem;
  }
}

.intro-title {
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: #d6d6d6;
  font-weight: 400;
  animation: titleAnimation 1.5s ease-in;
}

@keyframes titleAnimation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-bottom: -2rem;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
  }
}
```

The `hiAnimation` works just fine -- animating in exactly as intended -- but neither `nameAnimation` or `titleAnimation` work, even though they're formatted exactly the same way. Not sure what I'm missing, any help?

Answer (score 1):

would you reduce font-size: 20rem; to 2rem because it should work.
you have set very small time that's why when you scroll to see animation that is already done.
Let me know did it work for you.

Comment: The p tag set to 20rem is working correctly so the font size isn't the issue there. All of the animated elements are directly next to each other on the landing page of the site, so there's no scrolling happening that could cause the animations to be missed - the element in the `.hi` p tag animates just fine as soon as the page loads, but the others don't trigger even though they're right next to it.